# Query Rule to promote SharePoint Sites in search result

Tags: 2013, search-results, enterprise-search

I'd like to promote sites in my search results, preferably using a query rule as described in this post https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/10/03/how-to-change-the-order-in-which-search-results-are-displayed-in-sharepoint-server-2013/

I figured that a Manual Condition would do as described in this image (I would Promote to top instead)

[image: Image from Technet]

However, I can't find what to use to instead of ContentType since sites aren't a contenttype. I'm thinking of something like `ResultType:Site`

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used that approach, but you could use `ContentClass:STS_Site` for site collections and/or `ContentClass:STS_Web` for sites.